# mapquest Community Edition (open data) for a commercial project

Tags: android, android-maps

Currently I'm developing an application which uses a map and geocoding functionality.

I'm using the mapquest api which works like a charm.

As a non-native-speaker I had some trouble understanding the mapquest terms.

Can I use mapquest android api/library in conjunction with Community Edition (open data) for a commercial project?

Comment: This would be a question best directed at MapQuest's support team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be used for commercial projects

This is the reply I got from mapquest:

> Thank you for your inquiry.  I’m happy to answer your questions
>   regarding the terms of use for the MapQuest Community Edition.  Yes
>   you can use the Community Edition in an Android application that is
>   for commercial use.  You will still have the geocode limit of 5,000
>   per day and the driving direction limit of 5,000 per day.